# Ubuntu 16.04 /bin/kill bug?

Tags: process, hadoop, kill

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on the virtual machine using VMware.
To test my MapReduce code, I also installed hadoop 2.7.3 and setup a single node cluster.

When I execute MapReduce algorithm, every process including NameNode, DataNode, ResourceManager, NodeManager  and the ssh session that I using is killed without any warning.

To investigate, I created a wrapper script that logs input parameters of /bin/kill process after I moved /bin/kill to /bin/temp/kill

```
date >> /home/user/log.txt
echo "$@" >> /home/user/log.txt
echo "$#" >> /home/user/log.txt
w >> /home/user/log.txt
/bin/temp/kill $@
```

After MapReduce Job is started, every process is killed and the containment of the log file is as follows:

```
Sun Aug 28 03:39:19 KST 2016
-0 -18953
2
03:39:19 up 14 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.74, 2.65, 1.78
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user   tty1                      03:36    3:27   0.06s  0.06s -bash

Sun Aug 28 03:39:19 KST 2016
-15 -18844
2
03:39:19 up 14 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.74, 2.65, 1.78
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user   tty1                      03:36    3:27   0.06s  0.00s     /usr/bin/clear_console -q
```

As soon as "kill -0 -1xxxx" is called, my processed are killed due to the bug of kill reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1610499

I added ps ax >> /home/user/log.txt and process with pid 18844 was

```
 18844 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/hadoop-datastore/hadoop-2.7.3/nm-local-dir/usercache/user/appcache/application_1472323092836_0001/container_1472323092836_0001_01_000001/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1472323092836_0001/container_1472323092836_0001_01_000001 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog -Xmx1024m org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster 1>/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1472323092836_0001/container_1472323092836_0001_01_000001/stdout 2>/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1472323092836_0001/container_1472323092836_0001_01_000001/stderr
```

I think that some hadoop daemon such as NodeManager wanted to kill YarnChild since YarnChild uses more memory than it can use. But it results in killing all processes.

Q1. What is the meaning of killing a process whose process id is negative integer? Why isn't it a positive number as normal process has.

Q2. If it is another bug of Hadoop that invokes kill with a negative pid, how can I find which process invokes such as "kill -15 -18844"? I want to find the process and report the bug to the hadoop community.

I recompiled /bin/kill from procps-ng 3.3.12 and everything works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, bug reports aren't exactly what we do. Bug reports belong on Launchpad or GitHub - whichever the developers use

Comment: As for negative PID, man page states `Negative PID values may be used to choose whole process groups; see the PGID column in ps command out‐
       put. `

Comment: Might try adding `pstree $$ >> /home/user/log.txt` to your script to help find what's invoking the kill command.

Comment: NodeManager of Hadoop invokes /bin/kill to stop all process with gid, but it results in killing all processes due to the bug when gid starts with 1. Everything is clear and I should post it on Launchpad or GitHub!